# jQuery ajax not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my function to call ajax:

```
var sendAjax = function(type, data, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: homepage + 'server_ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      type: type,
      data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    callback(true, JSON.parse(data));
  }).fail(function() {
    console.log('NO');
    callback(false, {});
  });
};
```

1. Variable `homepage` contains valid URL. It is same domain, so this is not the problem.
2. My `server_ajax.php` has only this: `echo "awdawda wawddawawd";` - nothing more (testing purposes).
3. I tried to put breakpoints to `$.ajax...` and to the console logs. First breakpoint works, but functions `done` and `fail` never run.
4. No error show up in the browser console
5. My jQuery is include (I'm sure), I use `require.js` and everything else in this JS file using jQuery works well.
6. I also tried change URL to something invalid (like `server_ajax2.php`) and console prints error 404 - like it would.
7. Also tried with `dataType: 'json'` or removing `data` object...

Any ideas, what should I try? I also tried some answers on this site (don'r flag this as duplicate, I tried like everything), but nothing helped me.

Comment: Could you tell what is the exact problem? Is ajax call failing or is there any error in the browser console when you call this function?

Comment: Did you read my question to the end? It should print `console.log(data);` after complete. And, there is no error in browser console, it is totally clear.

Comment: Wow what a polite poster.  Makes me want to help you so much more!

Comment: If you're using Chrome open developer tools (F12) and open the Network tab before you run the ajax call. Execute your ajax call and you'll see a new entry in the table below. You should be able to see the status of the ajax call itself and see the response received from the server.

Comment: What I was asking was: here, you are just defining function to a variable. could you please tell how do you call this function? (like sendAjax(arg1,arg2,arg3))

Comment: are you sure that somewhere in your code you are even calling the `sendAjax` function?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `homepage` variable from the URL and using a relative path?

Comment: @cpshah I call it like this: `_.sendAjax('getter', 'isUserLogged', ...` and I'm using `require.js`, so this is at the top of file: `define(['jquery', 'functions'], function($, _) {...`. Functions.js is file, where is this `sendAjax` not actually variable, but it is `_.sendAjax = function(...`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes tried, same result.

Comment: @Jon there is screenshot from Network tab, it should works god then: http://prntscr.com/81ojz1

Comment: @low_rents Yes I'm, I had breakpoint on `$.ajax` and it stopped me there afte calling.

Comment: do you call the function anywhere?

Comment: @johnny5 look at the comments above you, there is also screenshot of calling.

Comment: you probably also need  dataType   : 'json',

Comment: @johnny5 tried, but same result, nothing in browser console.

Comment: I have a feeling it not hitting your server do can you hit a break point on the server?

Comment: @johnny5 look: http://prntscr.com/81ojz1 - it returns data from server (netwrok tab in developer tools), but it doesn't proceed javascript

Comment: also you probably need contentType: 'json' for sending to the server data type is for receiving

Comment: Didn't help... I don't know what else I could try

Comment: Wierd, is it still causing issues?

Comment: @johnny5 not anymore, I fixed it after some time. I don't even know, what was the cause. I just removed customized JS error handler and it works. Its weird, because in another project I'm using same error handler but all ajaxes work... Whatever, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing the following on the `server_ajax.php` file:

```
echo json_encode('awdawda wawddawawd');
header('X-PHP-Response-Code: 200', true, 200);
```

This encodes the response as JSON so that your JavaScript code can read the content, and gives the standard success header (`200 OK`) to the page so that the `$.ajax` code knows the query was successful.

Comment: sorry but that's not an answer, that's just pure guessing.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this, since your getting data back perhaps its your success failure functions.

```
$.ajax({
  url: homepage + 'server_ajax.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType : 'json',
  contentType: 'text/plain',
  data: {
    type: type,
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    callback(true, JSON.parse(data));
   },
   error: function() {
     console.log('NO');
     callback(false, {});
   }
});
```

Comment: Success, error, and complete functions are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. They will eventually be removed. Done, fail, and always should be used in their place.

Comment: As @Jon said, these functions are deprected. Actually, its same what I have. But look at the question comments, I have already fixed it.